# Polylang disable translation for posts

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

I'm using polylang on my wordpress page. I want to translate the pages, but keep the blog in only one language. 
I've used this hook:

```
function turn_blogposts_translation_off( $post_types, $is_settings ) {
  unset( $post_types['post'] );

  return $post_types;
}

add_filter( 'pll_get_post_types', 'turn_blogposts_translation_off', 10, 2 );
```

which does disable translations for posts, but if I am viewing my page in the second language, no blog posts are shown, since there are none in that language.

How can I show English posts (main language) while viewing the site in other languages?

Comment: I would also like to know how to do this.

Comment: I think you can do it like that, it's already explained in this doc page; https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/general/
`$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'lang' => 'fr', // use language slug in the query
    'showposts' => 5
));`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @ewroman's comment. The document already has an answer for that

> ###### Is it possible to query all languages?
>
> Yes it is. Example:
>
> ```php
> $posts = get_posts(array(
>    'post_type' => 'post',
>    'lang' => '', // query posts in all languages
>    'showposts' => 5
> ));
> ```

This `lang` filter can also apply to the `WP_Query` because their parameters are the same.

```php
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'lang'      => '', // query posts in all languages
);
$query = new WP_Query($query_args);
```